# Manga/manhwa where the main character didn't have mana/magic, but got one by getting punched by a fist filled with mana

Tags: story-identification, magic, manga, webcomics

It's about a main character who, if I remember correctly, didn't have mana.

But when he got one by getting punched by a fist filled with mana, he got a lot stronger to a point where nobody could move; their instinct told them not to.

He can't absorb powers and he starts from the bottom since i think he got sent back to time?

It's hard to remember it, but I think it was in full colour, and the MC had short (possibly orange) hair.

he got the mana through a tournament or a fight since the mc didnt have mana the opponent didnt use one too but when his opponent almost lose to him. his opponent used a punch thats full of mana

him experiencing the mana for the first time the mana shocked his body and was able to use mana which allowed him to unlock this awesome transformation

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this question by looking at the check lists in [this thread](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question), then [edit]ing it to include any further details that come to mind. In particular, it'd be helpful to know whether this was in full colour or mostly black & white.

Comment: Sounds a bit like the Atronarch sign in Elder Scrolls, unable to generate mana on his own, but can absorb attacks.

Comment: Was he native to the world? Transmigrated? Reincarnated? Isekaied? Does he have a "cheat system" or user interface?

Comment: ack i dont remember if he got reincarnated or travelled back to time but all i remember is that he got stronger alot after that mana fist hitted him

Comment: Your recent edit removed manhua from the title - does this mean that you're certain it wasn't a manhua? If so, do you remember if it is in color or mostly black&white? If it is in color, it's almost certainly a manhwa and not a manga. Knowing this would help narrow down searches.

Comment: ye it isnt a manhua since i dont read manhuas and it was either a manga or a manhwa recommendation by tiktok and its probably colored yeah its colored

Comment: Does this take place in a fantasy world or the modern world? Or explicitly in a game? Do they use the exact term "mana", or does he just get stronger? How many chapters of this did you read? More specifically, do you know when he gets hit by the mana fist? It sounds like something that would happen in the first chapter, but it'd be good to confirm that.

Comment: its not in a game , kinda modern world?. everyone has mana but hes the only one that doesnt have mana so he got stronger without it. i forgot how many chapters i red from it and he got hit by the mana fist not from the first chapter probably somewhere middle of the story and the manhwas not done yet i think

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late response but the manhwa you’re looking for is called ***[Reincarnation of the Veteran Soldier](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/s6znq5q/reincarnation-of-the-veteran-soldier)***.

> Army veteran's last go at the obstacle course turns lethal after a simple fall. A goddess presents an opportunity at new life as a hero! The protagonist ain't having any of it, he was supposed to retire and become a civilian. The arrogant Goddess drops him down to survive while having her own evil schemes. How will his new life progress after encountering another Goddess, a spy and his past life's junior?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to explain why you think this is the correct answer, i.e. specifying any plot points that match the description given in the question, and any that don't.